# Back button in a viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a gridview with 26 buttons that leads to a viewpager with 26 elements. If I'm on the 25th element and I click the back button, i go to the 24th -> 23rd -> 22nd etc. Is there a way that I can go from any element in the viewpager to the gridview with the use of the back button?

```
case 0: {
                        Intent A = new Intent(v.getContext(), ScreenSlidePagerActivity.class);
                        A.putExtra("viewpager_position", 0);
                        mContext.startActivity(A);
                        //getItem(0);
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: We need more info here,  how does the gridview start showing the viewpager?

Comment: edited it with a snippet of code

Comment: since you are starting a new activity to show the viewpager,  the back button should return you to the previous activity that shows a grid.  If this isn't the case I suspect that something might be off in how you are displaying the viewpager (perhaps backbutton is disabled, fragment stacking implementation bug, or you have a finish somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

You can override its action:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     // your custom code
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()